# Fixing legacy code without breaking everything

Tags: php, legacy-code

I have some code like this :

```
somefunc($row['some_key']);
```

Sometimes, $row might not have 'some_key' which logs an `Undefined index` warning.

> > How do you fix this warning without changing the current behavior of the program ?

I know I need to fix the problem to the source but this is a legacy codebase T_T

### My attemp

```
if(!isset($row['some_key'])){
    somefunc(null);
}
else{
    somefunc($row['some_key']);
}
```

Is this equivalent ?

Comment: Why make complex code, just write `if (isset($row['some_key'])) {}` and that's all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it is equivalent, but you can be more terse (if you're interested) with a ternary operator (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php you have to scroll a little, unfortunate, they don't have any anchor for it)...

```
somefunc( (isset($row['some_key'])) ? $row['some_key'] : null );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

```
somefunc( isset($row['some_key']) ? $row['some_key'] : null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the structure of the entire program, I would suggest adding a simple [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) check before accessing any variable that throws an Undefined index/offset error.

```
if (isset($row['some_key'])) {
    somefunc($row['some_key']);
}
```

This way, **the function will get called if and only if the `some_key` index exists.** You could shorten it further using a ternary expression, but it would not be very readable, so I suggest using `if-else` blocks instead.

Comment: I think somefunc still get called even if the key is undefined, isn't ?

Comment: I mean, in my example, if you just call `somefunc($row['some_key']);` and the 'some_key' is not defined in the $row array, somefunc would get called.

Comment: @Nico: yes. Which is why I recommend adding an `isset()` check ***before*** calling the function to see if the key exists or not.

Comment: Ok, but that change the behavior of the program becasue `somefunc` gets called no matter what `$row['some_key']` is set or not.

Comment: @Nico: Add this `isset()` check where the function is called. Then it will get called only if the index exists. (You can also achieve the same thing using `array_key_exists()`.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50904/discussion-between-amal-murali-and-nico)